# Digitally signing an application that is compiled from source file?

Tags: c#, .net, digital-signature

I have an application which let me select some options, change name, and other preferences and then click the Build button. A file named source.cs will be compiled through CSharpCodeProvider and new program will appear.

How to digitally sign the compiled program (Self-signing) at compile time. So the built program will be digitally signed ?

Is it sufficient to digitally sign the Builder to generate digitally signed programs from the Builder ?

Comment: This makes no sense.  Why do you want to sign them?  What's the point of self-signing?  If you actually meant "giving it a strong name" then it still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assembly signing is done by Al.exe, ie the assembly linker. There is of course API's [doing the signing part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964998.aspx), but I would prefer deploy the solution with [ILmerge.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) and shell it as a command line to sign te assembly after is built. the command line to use is basically this one:

```
ilmerge nonsigned.dll /keyfile:key.snk /out:signed.dll
```

so you don't exactly merge since there is a single assembly, but as a side effect the assembly will be signed.